# Prefetching not working on dynamic routes Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm getting all my links from an API or dynamically and I'm having trouble Prefetching them and I can't seem to figure out why.

All the pages are server-side rendered.

Every time I hover a link I get this error:

```
GET https://development.server/_next/static/0_YgyPL5ev7zYK3SSr7J-/pages/page.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404. page-loader.js:33
```

**Example of link that I'm using**

```
onst Header = ({ props, slugTv }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { tv } = router.query;

  return (
      <header>
        <div className="header">
          <Link href="/[tv]/" as={`/${tv}/`}>
            <a>
              <img src={renderSwitch(tv)} alt={`${tv} logo`} />
            </a>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </header>
```

If I missed some crucial detail that please comment and I'll update the question, this is my first next project.

**UPDATE:**

Page folder tree

```
-pages
--[tv]//folder
--category//folder
---[cat].js
--index.js
-index.js
```

Thank you

Comment: It may only happen in development mode. Have you tried to build and start a production server and check again? You can do so by running `next build` and `next start`.

Comment: @Hangindev Yes, this error is from a live server but on a development pipeline stage.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean "this error is *not* from a live server but on a development pipeline stage."?

Comment: @Hangindev Yes :)

Comment: I see. According to [Next.js Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerprefetch), Next.js doesn't prefetch pages on development.

Comment: @Hangindev the same error occurs on production as well, i don't think that that is the issue. Any other sugestions?

Comment: Okay. Have you set up any `getStaticProps`, `getStaticPaths` and `getServerSideProps` in `[tv].js`?

Comment: No, the ``[tv]`` is a folder and the index.js in it dose not have any of the mentioned props.
I updated the question with the Page folder tree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215808/discussion-between-hangindev-and-filip-simin).

Comment: When you get this error, the link that you are trying to prefetch is `/[tv]/` where the `tv` param is `page`?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be related to the trailing `/` in your `as`.

Changing to this, should work:

```
<Link href="/[tv]/" as={`/${tv}`}>
```

From the error, it looks like it is trying to prefetch: `https://development.server/_next/static/0_YgyPL5ev7zYK3SSr7J-/pages/page.js`

whereas it should be trying to fetch: 
`https://development.server/_next/static/0_YgyPL5ev7zYK3SSr7J-/pages/[tv].js`

So, looks like it's interpreting the link as a whole new page, instead of the `href` that you pointed to. (mismatch?)

I found [this](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8913) as something that might be relevant